# VPN + WPF Application

Tags: sql, wpf, vpn

I currently have a SQL server setup within a VPN.

I will be using a WPF application that queries the SQL server. This application will be on a tablet used from various locations outside of the VPN. I want to be able to query the database from outside of the VPN without having to use a VPN Client. I don't know what the best approach would be to keep the data transfer secure.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: The (I assume) Windows tablet does allow setting up Virtual private tunnels right?

Comment: @Max, I am not sure on that. I know I can connect to the VPN from the tablet, but I'm trying to eliminate this extra step. I want a way to transfer data to and from the tablet in a secure manner without having to open a VPN client application.